# Grails/GORM belongsTo Back Reference Naming

Tags: grails, grails-orm, belongs-to, grails-domain-class

I created the domains in Grails to focus on the business logic behind our process. In several cases, this translates to a back reference that GORM generates that exceeds the Oracle limits and generates a "ORA-00972: identifier is too long" error. I was able to use the `static mapping` block to remap the long table name, but I can't figure out how to do the same for the generated back reference.

Without exposing any company confidential information, the following example illustrates the problem.

```
class UnfortunatelyLongClassName {
    static mapping = {
        table "long_class" // This works great!
    }

    List<Part> parts

    static hasMany = [parts:Part]
}

class Part {
    String name

    // This generates UNFORTUNATELY_LONG_CLASS_NAME_ID and causes the error
    static belongsTo = [UnfortunatelyLongClassName]
}
```

Rough DDL of the tables generated...

```
LONG_CLASS (
  ID number(19, 0) not null,
  VERSION number(19, 0) not null,
  primary key (id),
);

PART (
  ID number(19, 0) not null,
  VERSION number(19, 0) not null,
  NAME varchar2(255),
  PARTS_IDX number(10, 0),
  UNFORTUNATELY_LONG_CLASS_NAME_ID number(19, 0) not null,
  primary key (id),
  foreign key FK589895C372DB95A (UNFORTUNATELY_LONG_CLASS_NAME_ID) references UNFORTUNATELY_LONG_CLASS_NAME(ID)
);
```

**Are there any static mapping commands or other Grails/GORM tricks to get this to create a shorter identifier?**

If I use the following...

```
static belongsTo = [unfortunatelyLongClassName:UnfortunatelyLongClassName]

static mapping = {
    unfortunatelyLongClassName column:"ulcn_id"
}
```

I get the following errors...

```
| Error 2012-07-24 17:53:49,060 [pool-7-thread-1] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
Message: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.InvalidPropertyException: No property found for name [unfortunatelyLongClassName] for class [class mycompany.myproject.mypackage.Part]
   Line | Method
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread

Caused by InvalidPropertyException: No property found for name [unfortunatelyLongClassName] for class [class mycompany.myproject.mypackage.Part]
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2012-07-24 17:53:49,094 [pool-7-thread-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.InvalidPropertyException: No property found for name [unfortunatelyLongClassName] for class [class mycompany.myproject.mypackage.Part]
Message: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.InvalidPropertyException: No property found for name [unfortunatelyLongClassName] for class [class mycompany.myproject.mypackage.Part]
   Line | Method
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread

Caused by InvalidPropertyException: No property found for name [unfortunatelyLongClassName] for class [class mycompany.myproject.mypackage.Part]
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Map syntax in `belongsTo` to generate the backlink and rename it via a mapping:

```
static belongsTo = [unfortunatelyLongClassName:UnfortunatelyLongClassName]

static mapping = {
    unfortunatelyLongClassName column:"ulcn_id"
}
```

---

`belongsTo` should also work with fields in your Domain class, so you could do:

```
UnfortunatelyLongClassName unfortunatelyLongClassName

static belongsTo = UnfortunatelyLongClassName

static mapping = {
    unfortunatelyLongClassName column:"ulcn_id"
}
```

---

Since the previous versions throw missing property exceptions, you could try creating the property with a short name and skipping the mapping block:

```
UnfortunatelyLongClassName ulcn

static belongsTo = UnfortunatelyLongClassName
```

Comment: I tried this earlier and got this ERROR... 

| Error 2012-07-24 16:49:25,431 [pool-7-thread-1] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
Message: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.InvalidPropertyException: No property found for name [unfortunatelyLongClassName ] for class [class mycompany.myproject.mypackage.Part]

Comment: I added another method you could try in the answer

Comment: I tried both of these initially, but I got a missing property error. I've edited the question to include the settings I tried and the error stack I got back. I'm using Grails 2.0.4 running in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Ok, one more idea to try in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The first two methods work fine. I wound up having a corrupted Grails project that was the root cause of my issue. I checked the project out of source control into a new folder and everything worked fine... I hate when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to rename the id of the long class? Like:

```
static mapping = {
    id name: 'simple_id_name'
}
```

Comment: The issue is with the back reference in the short `PART` table. If I used this on the long class name table, then I don't see how that it would help. Am I missing something?

Comment: In your example you didn't use belongsTo with a back reference (like [longClass: LongClassName]) so I assumed you didn't want one. But ok.
I think that to the Part table be created, it needs to reference the LongClass id. The Id, if you do not specify a column name, will be the name of the class plus '_id' and that's where the problem might be. Manually specify the LongClass id so that when Part needs to reference it, it will be alright. Try it.